# Highcharts Map Map-Pies Angular2 Typescript not working

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I'm trying to build a Highcharts Map (europe map) with map-pies with Angular 2 in Typescript.

I took this demo example -> https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/map-pies

[image]

**What I just managed:**

1) Adding the europe map, join my data and display them in a tooltip.

2) Draw some pies with correct data in different sizes (top-left corner always)

But I failed to set the position of these pies (and let them stay when the map is zoomed or moved)

I also tried proj4.js libary -> https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/latlon

**I have serveral issues:**

1) How can I extend the Highcharts.seriesType as in the demo "New map-pie series type that also allows lat/lon as center option"

2) `clip: true, // For map navigation` - does not exist in Angular 2 TS

3)  `var point = chart.fromLatLonToPoint(options.center);` - does not exist in Angular 2 TS

4) There is no `sizeFormatter: function ()` and no `getCenter: function ()`

5) Pass lat/lon to center doesn't work because of 1)

```
center: {
            lat: centerLat + (pieOffset.lat || 0),
            lon: centerLon + (pieOffset.lon || 0)
        }
```

6) Because of 1) & 2) I set the pies position on the map without lat/lon but with x/y coordinate I get from the country on the map - and because of that if the map is moved the position are wrong

Did someone tried this before in angular2 ts and did not failed? thanks for any help

---

What I did so far: https://jsfiddle.net/0jhqmaeu/

[image]

---

Solved it with a workaround:

1) Add the pies to `plotX`/`plotY` of the state

2) Add eventlistener `mouseup` (detect map movement)

3) Add eventlistener `xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes` (detect map zoom)

4) Event callback remove all pies and add on new position (states x/y position)

5) Optional: Set visibility only if state is visible

[image]

Comment: Please, provide us with the example that you have done so far.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0jhqmaeu/